# ndb Model - retrieve ordered set of property names

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, app-engine-ndb

I'm often asked to export data stored in NDB models to csv. For that purpose, I usually ended up writing a model like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Foo(ndb.Model):
    monty = ndb.StringProperty()
    python = ndb.StringProperty()

    @property
    @classmethod
    def fieldnames(cls):
        return ['monty', 'python']
```

and in the export module something along the lines of

```
# pseudocode ...

query = Foo.gql('where monty = :1', 'bunny')
data = [littlefoo._to_dict() for littlefoo in query]
fieldnames = Foo.fieldnames
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, dialect=dialect)
writer.writerows(data)
```

Note that the fieldnames method is needed for determining the order of the fields in the output csv. The problem with this approach is that for any model with a significant number of attributes, adding the `fieldnames` method is ugly duplicate work. Ideally, I'd like to simply order the properties as I declare them, and retrieve them in the same order for `fieldnames`. Is there a way to retrieve these properties in order? `Foo._properties` is ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I was looking to do the same, and came up with a simpler solution than the accepted answer.  Just in case you're still interested, take a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54744631/1965404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, this isn't possible without parsing the source for yourself.  Luckily, with python's "batteries included" mentality, this isn't too hard.  You can use `inspect` to get the source code and then you can use `ast` to parse the source and order things:

```
import ast
import inspect

class NodeTagger(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_attribute_names = {}

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        for target in node.targets:
            self.class_attribute_names[target.id] = target.lineno

    # Don't visit Assign nodes inside Function Definitions.
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, unused_node):
        return None

def order_properties(model):
    properties = model._properties
    source = inspect.getsource(model)
    tree = ast.parse(source)
    visitor = NodeTagger()
    visitor.visit(tree)
    attributes = visitor.class_attribute_names
    model._ordered_property_list = sorted(properties, key=lambda x:attributes[x])
    return model


@order_properties
class Foo(object):
    c = 1
    b = 2
    a = 3

    # Add a _properties member to simulate an `ndb.Model`.
    _properties = {'a': object, 'b': object, 'c': object}

print Foo._ordered_property_list
```

Note that the approach here is almost general.  I used the knowledge that `ndb.Model`s have a `_properties` attribute, but that information could probably be gleaned from `dir` or `inspect.getmembers` so `order_properties` could be modified so that it works completely generally.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks a lot! That approach might have occurred to me, but I certainly would have thought it to be way too complicated to implement. Glad you showed me otherwise.

Comment: @Alice -- I've been playing around with `ast` a lot lately.  It's surprisingly useful and easy to use despite the somewhat opaque documentation.

Comment: This answer is pretty cool. It's a pity ndb didn't use an OrderedDict for _properties in it's original implementation.  I am driving some forms off the schema, and have been storing a list of names (properties) so I can be explicit about the order in the form, and drop off properties like date_created which aren't required in the forms.

Comment: @TimHoffman -- It wouldn't have done any good.  `_properties` is almost certainly picked up via a `ndb.Model`'s `__metaclass__`.  Since it has to abide by the rules of python metaclasses in general, the class namespace is passed as a regular `dict`.  In other words, this is a restriction in python, not the implementation of `ndb`.  Of course, when guido programmed it, I think he could have done basically what I just did in the metaclass -- But that code complexity addition probably wasn't worth the added overhead and minimal gain.

Comment: +1 for the creative approach! But there is a simpler solution for this particular problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54744631/1965404

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making this up, it's probably full of errors, but hopefully it starts you down the right path:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import Property

def get_field_names(ndbmodel):
    result = []
    all_fields = dir(ndbmodel)
    for field in all_fields:
        if isinstance(getattr(ndbmodel, field), Property):
            result.append(field)
    return result.sort()
```

Comment: `dir` returns the results in alphabetical order and `type(...) == Property` won't work.  Usually you're working with a subclass of `Property` (e.g. `StringProperty`).

Comment: Oops, misread the question, I thought it was asking for a sorted order.  Should have been isinstance() instead of type().

Comment: Yeah, this one works fine for alphabetical order, just not what I was looking for :) Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

#### If using `google.appengine.ext.db`:

`db.Property` instances have an attribute called `creation_counter`, which is incremented each time a new instance is created.  So to get a list of properties sorted in declaration order, you can do something like:

```
sorted(Foo.properties().items(), key=lambda np: np[1].creation_counter)
```

(where `Foo` is an instance of `db.Model`)

#### If using `google.appengine.ext.ndb`:

Same thing, except the `ndb.Property` attribute is called `_creation_counter`, so the equivalent code would be:

```
sorted(Foo._properties.items(), key=lambda np: np[1]._creation_counter)
```

(where `Foo` is an instance of `ndb.Model`)