# how to collect class variables while preserving the order

Tags: python, inheritance, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree, metaclass

I'm trying to create schema classes similar to SQLAlchemy declarative_base.  The schema classes should be extensible using inheritance.  Here is my attempt so far. It works fine except the properties (class variables) are sorted in the alphabetical order.

```
import inspect
class BaseProp(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
class StringProp(BaseProp): pass
class EmailProp(BaseProp): pass

class BaseSchema(object):
    @classmethod
    def _collect_props(cls):
        prop_filter =  lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)) and issubclass(a.__class__, BaseProp)
        return inspect.getmembers(cls, prop_filter)

    @classmethod
    def as_list(cls):
        return cls._collect_props()

    @classmethod
    def as_dict(cls):
        return dict(cls._collect_props())

class UserIdentSchema(BaseSchema):
    email = EmailProp('email')
    password = StringProp('password')

class UserProfileSchema(UserIdentSchema):
    name = StringProp('name')
    phone = StringProp('phone')

from pprint import pprint
pprint(UserProfileSchema.as_list())
```

Here is the result.  Notice the properties are sorted by the alphabetical order.

```
[('email', <__main__.EmailProp object at 0x10518a950>),
 ('name', <__main__.StringProp object at 0x10517d910>),
 ('password', <__main__.StringProp object at 0x10517d8d0>),
 ('phone', <__main__.StringProp object at 0x10517d950>)]
```

I want to have the base schema props at the top, then props from the subclasses.  What's the best way to achieve this?  Do I have to go through AST...?

EDIT:  I need to keep the order of properties within a class as well.

Comment: You don't have to go through AST, but you'll have to walk through the class hierarchy yourself.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- If you care how `email` and `password` are ordered, you need to look at the AST since they get passed to the BaseSchema metaclass (`type`) as a dict ...

Comment: Note, I did something similar in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381633/748858).  The main difference is that answer didn't deal with inheritance while it's important here.  It wouldn't be too hard to extend the previous answer to deal with inheritance though...

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the order of props within a class as well.

Comment: @mgilson: True, but that wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks, I've never tried getting class hierarchy.  I will study about it.

Comment: @mgilson thanks, I've read the question and the answer.  It's essentially the same problem.   I am thinking I might be able to put something in the `BaseProp.__init__` such as getting caller info from the frame, and create a list of props...

Comment: Ah I guess not.  It's a horrible idea unless all subclasses are declared within a single file ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's a working solution -- I don't guarantee that this is production worthy code ... e.g. I haven't thought too much about what would happen if you tried to mix in another (non-`BaseSchema`) class with a `BaseSchema` subclass.  I think that *might* work, but you'd need to try it out to see ...

```
import ast
import inspect
from collections import OrderedDict

class _NodeTagger(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_attribute_names = {}

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        for target in node.targets:
            self.class_attribute_names[target.id] = target.lineno

    # Don't visit Assign nodes inside Function Definitions.
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, unused_node):
        return None


class BaseProp(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class StringProp(BaseProp): pass


class EmailProp(BaseProp): pass


class _BaseSchemaType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls._properties = OrderedDict()
        for b in bases:
          # if the object has a metaclass which is this
          # class (or subclass of this class...)
          # then we add it's properties to our own.
          if issubclass(type(b), _BaseSchemaType):
            cls._properties.update(b._properties)

        # Finally, we add our own properties.  We find our own source code
        # read it and tag the nodes where we find assignment.
        source = inspect.getsource(cls)
        nt = _NodeTagger()
        nt.visit(ast.parse(source))
        attr_names = nt.class_attribute_names
        properties = {n: prop for n, prop in dct.items()
                      if isinstance(prop, BaseProp)}
        sorted_attrs = sorted(properties.items(),
                             key=lambda item: attr_names[item[0]])
        cls._properties.update(sorted_attrs)

    # methods on a metaclass are basically just classmethods ...
    def as_list(cls):
      return list(cls._properties.items())

    def as_dict(cls):
      return cls._properties.copy()


class BaseSchema(object):
    __metaclass__ = _BaseSchemaType

class UserIdentSchema(BaseSchema):
    email = EmailProp('email')
    password = StringProp('password')

class UserProfileSchema(UserIdentSchema):
    name = StringProp('name')
    phone = StringProp('phone')

from pprint import pprint
pprint(UserProfileSchema.as_list())
```

Sorry about the metaclass -- But it really does make things easier here.  Now all the magic happens when the class gets imported -- No messy introspection every time you call `as_list`.  It also gives me quick access to the class's properties and it's bases which I would need to pull out of `__dict__` and `__bases__` otherwise (or figure it out from `inspect`).

Comment: wow this is super cool.  I learned something from your code more than the answer to the original question.

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi -- It gave me something new to think about with regards to metaclasses.  I think I'm _finally_ getting close to the point where I actually understand them (although there are a few corners that I'm still not completely sure about -- e.g. `Metaclass.__call__`.  I have thoughts about how that _should_ work, but I haven't had time to try it out).  Anyhow, you really don't _need_ a metaclass here, you _could_ take my `__init__` and drop it into your `_collect_props` without too many modifications ... But ... It's fun anyway :-)